# Parsing a colon-separated values with broken quotes in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, csv, sed

I have a colon-separated file `cik.coleft.c`, which looks like this:

```
!J INC:0001438823:
#1 A LIFESAFER HOLDINGS, INC.:0001509607:
#1 ARIZONA DISCOUNT PROPERTIES LLC:0001457512:
#1 PAINTBALL CORP:0001433777:
$ LLC:0001427189:
& S MEDIA GROUP LLC:0001447162:
&TV COMMUNICATIONS INC.:0001479357:
'MKTG, INC.':0000886475:
11:11 CAPITAL CORP.:0001463262:
```

It's a two-column `csv` where separating commas were replaced with colons. Meanwhile, single quotes escape values with commas, instead of values with colons (the separator).

But the first column contains colons, which break parsers. So when I try to convert `cik.coleft.c` into normal `csv`...

```
curl -o cik.coleft.c 'https://www.sec.gov/edgar/NYU/cik.coleft.c'

in2csv --format 'csv' -d ':' -q "'" -e 'latin1' cik.coleft.c > cik.coleft.csv
```

... I get four and more columns.

I tried reading the lines with `sed`, but haven't succeed.

How can I convert this into a proper two-column table?

Comment: can you choose a different delimiter which won't conflict with things like `11:11`?

Comment: So, the only incorrect colon is the `11:11` in the last row?

Comment: You -- or whoever created the file -- broke the format by replacing the delimiters without reanalyzing the quoting requirements for each field. Naively changing the delimiters in an "X"-separated values file destroys information, leading to this kind of ambiguity. (This doesn't help you, I know, but it's a lesson for the future. If someone else broke the file, you could legitimately complain.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` and do some string manipulation with `subtr` and `length`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{col1=substr($0,1,length($0)-12);col2=substr($0,length($0)-10, 10);print col1,col2}' yourfile
```

That sets the Output Field Seperator `OFS` to pipe `|`. It delineates the two columns using `substr()` and `length()`. Column 1 is found by starting at character 1 and ending at 12 characters before the end of the record. Column 2 is found by starting 10 characters before the end of the record and grabbing 10 characters following.

Test output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{col1=substr($0,1,length($0)-12);col2=substr($0,length($0)-10, 10);print col1,col2}' test
!J INC|0001438823
#1 A LIFESAFER HOLDINGS, INC.|0001509607
#1 ARIZONA DISCOUNT PROPERTIES LLC|0001457512
#1 PAINTBALL CORP|0001433777
$ LLC|0001427189
& S MEDIA GROUP LLC|0001447162
&TV COMMUNICATIONS INC.|0001479357
'MKTG, INC.'|0000886475
11:11 CAPITAL CORP.|0001463262
```

This only works because your second field appears to always be a 10 digit number. If that varies in other parts of the file, then you'll have to go a different route.

Answer (score 2):

you can approach it from backwards

```
$ rev file | sed 's/:/~/3' | rev | column -ts:

!J INC                              0001438823
#1 A LIFESAFER HOLDINGS, INC.       0001509607
#1 ARIZONA DISCOUNT PROPERTIES LLC  0001457512
#1 PAINTBALL CORP                   0001433777
$ LLC                               0001427189
& S MEDIA GROUP LLC                 0001447162
&TV COMMUNICATIONS INC.             0001479357
'MKTG, INC.'                        0000886475
11~11 CAPITAL CORP.                 0001463262
```

knowing that there are two columns, we reverse the line and replace the third instance of the `:` with `~`.

If you have more than one extra need to replaced, with gnu sed use `g3` instead of `3` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

The strategy is to match through the data, but with the lines reversed left to right. For that, we redirect the input using `@(next ...)` to a lazy `:list` of lines, produced by [lazily mapping](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02A03B1C) the output of [`(get-lines)`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-00B65D06) through the `reverse` function. The following is `fixcolon.txr`:

```
@(next :list @[mapcar* reverse (get-lines)])
@(repeat)
@  (assert)
@  (cases)
:@right:'@left'
@  (or)
:@right:@left
@  (end)
@  (do (put-line (reverse
                   (if (break-str left ":")
                     `:@right:'@left'`
                     `:@right:@left`))))
@(end)
```

Basically there are only two cases: we have a single quoted left or we don't. We want to remove the single quotes if they are present, and re-instate them only if the field contains colons.

The following extra line has been added to the data:

```
11:11 CA:PI:TAL CORP.:0001463262:
```

Output:

```
$ txr fixcolon.txr < data
!J INC:0001438823:
#1 A LIFESAFER HOLDINGS, INC.:0001509607:
#1 ARIZONA DISCOUNT PROPERTIES LLC:0001457512:
#1 PAINTBALL CORP:0001433777:
$ LLC:0001427189:
& S MEDIA GROUP LLC:0001447162:
&TV COMMUNICATIONS INC.:0001479357:
MKTG, INC.:0000886475:
'11:11 CAPITAL CORP.':0001463262:
'11:11 CA:PI:TAL CORP.':0001463262:
```

The superfluous quoting is gone around `MKTG, INC.`.  Quotes are introduced around the `11:11 ...` fields. (No attempt is made to handle embedded single quotes, since the sample data and question text do not specify or imply any requirements).

The [`@(assert)`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0294EF6B) ensures that the pattern matching blows up with an exception on data which doesn't match the cases that follow. The directive effectively says "everything after me matches, or else I throw!" Without it, the `@(repeat)` directive will skip over non-matching data. (If told not to skip using `:gap 0` it will stop at the first nonmatching line. Then to catch this issue we need an assertion that we are at EOF).

```
$ txr fixcolon.txr
foo:bar:
junk!
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
foo:bar:
txr: unhandled exception of type assert:
txr: (fixcolon.txr:3) assertion (at var:2)
txr: during evaluation at fixcolon.txr:3 of form (assert)
```